# Let $\beta$ be a nondegenerate, symmetrical bilinear form on $\mathbb{R^2}$. Is it true that $\forall v\in \mathbb{R^2}: \beta(v,v)=0 \iff v=0 $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\beta$ be a nondegenerate, symmetrical bilinear form on $\mathbb{R^2}$.
Is it true that $\forall v\in \mathbb{R^2}: \beta(v,v)=0 \iff v=0 $
?

My attempt:

$\beta$ is symmetrical, so $\forall v,w \in \mathbb{R^2}: \beta(v,w)=\beta(w,v)$

Furthermore $ker(\beta)=\{v\in \mathbb{R^2} | \forall w \in \mathbb{R^2}: \beta(v, w)=0\} $

$\beta$ is nondegenerate, so the kernel is trivial.

The problem is, I do not see that $\beta(v,v)=0 \implies v \in ker(\beta)$, since it does not state what happens if I change the second argument.

Are there any counterexamples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only there are counterexamples, but there is a specific name for this phenomenon. A symmetric bilinear form on a $\Bbb R$-vector space such that $\forall v, (\beta(v,v)=0\longleftrightarrow v=0)$ is called *anisotropic*. In general, anisotropy implies non-degeneracy, but not the other way around: in fact, you can show as an exercise that a symmetric bilinear form $\beta$ on a real vector space is anisotropic if and only if either $\beta$ or $-\beta$ is positive definite.

A classical example is on $\Bbb R^2$, $$\beta((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)):=x_1y_2+x_2y_1=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\end{pmatrix}$$

As you can see, the vectors of the canonical base satisfy $\beta(v,v)=0$, but the associated matrix is non-singular.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct; the claim is not true.  As a counterexample, let $G=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, and define $\beta:\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ by $\beta(v,w)=(v,Gw)$.  If $v_a=\begin{pmatrix}a\\a\end{pmatrix}$ for any $a\in\mathbb R$, then $\beta(v_a,v_a)=0$.  But $\beta$ is nondegenerate, for if $v\in\ker\beta$, then $\beta(v,w)=\lambda_w(v,w)=0$ for each eigenvector $w:Gw=\lambda_w w$ of $G$.  Since $G$ is symmetric, its eigenvectors span $\mathbb R^2$, so $v=0$.